# Ajax support In h:selectOneMenu

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have to call backend code as soon as one value is selected from drop-down list. I am using JSF 2.0. In JSF 1.2 I did it by using `<a4j:support>` in `<h:selectOneMenu>`, but I am not geting how to do it in JSF 2.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `<f:ajax>` tag. It's much similar to the `<a4j:support>`.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.selectItems}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.valueChanged}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

with

```
public void valueChanged() {
    // ...
}
```

The `<f:ajax>` has also an `event` attribute which already defaults to `valueChange` when used in `<h:selectOneMenu>`, so it is been omitted.