# Html dropdown. Change Div based on dropdown

Tags: html, jsf-2

Hey can anyone help me out i am trying to display a div on screen depending on what i select on a drop-down menu

```
<------------DropdownDiv---------->

    <div id="recordActivityDropdownDiv" style="padding: 5px">
        <h:selectOneMenu id="recordActivityDropdown" style="width:200px;" value="">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Email" itemValue="1"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Letter" itemValue="2"/>                                
        </h:selectOneMenu>  
    </div>

<------------Display this is letter is selected in dropdown menu Div---------->

    <div style="height:100%; width:99%; float:left">
        <div style="padding-top: 15px; padding-left: 5px; width: 20%; float: left;">
        letter:
        </div>
        <div style="height:100%; width:77%; float:left">
            <div style="padding: 5px; float:left;">
                <h:inputText id="letterbox" style="width:200px" value="" />
        </div>              
    </div>
```

Comment: As you're using jsf, why don't you replace such div with a JSF container? Then when you select your choice just update it with the selected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, your code would look a bit like this :

```xml
...
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectValue} id="recordActivityDropdown" style="width:200px;" value="">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Email" itemValue="1"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Letter" itemValue="2"/>
        <f:ajax listener="#{bean.valueChanged}" update="myGroup" />                                
    </h:selectOneMenu>  
...

...
<h:panelGroup id="myGroup" style="height:100%; width:99%; float:left">
    <div style="padding-top: 15px; padding-left: 5px; width: 20%; float: left;">
        letter: <h:outputText value="#{bean.selectValue}" />
    </div>
    ...              
</h:panelGroup>
...
```

This will update (via `ajax`) the now `panelGroup` that is your "div".  It will take the value of the `selectOneMenu` and print it to the div.

See also :

- [Ajax support In h:selectOneMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873711/ajax-support-in-hselectonemenu)
- [how to get value from <h:selectOneMenu>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584223/how-to-get-value-from-hselectonemenu)